# How to do a task every time a frame is recorded?

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture, android-mediarecorder

I'm starting on developing for android and I'm a little confused.

I programmed a simple video recorder using `MediaRecorder`, now I am taking other extra data and I want to save this data every time I record a frame (so later I can use this data to process every frame), but I am not sure how to do this.

Maybe using `Camera.PreviewCallback` or how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way is always start with the google docs. They have the best documentation. If you just started then I suggest to read everything is related to the Camera and how Android handles it.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

I made a live video streaming application a while ago and I used SurfaceView with Camera class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html

Comment: I've already read those links before posting, and I already use SurfaceView and Camera class (and also MediaRecorder) but I have no clue on how to do what I want. Searching a little more I realized I can't use the PreviewCalback beacuse it's not called when the camera starts to record